# Getting error when I tried to substitute a value in Python string using string formatting in Python

Tags: python

I have this String

```
S="191042709832779540946_1513246254239&source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22match_all%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22from%22%3A%s%2C%22size%22%3A20000%2C%22facets%22%3A%7B%22_type%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22_type%22%2C%22size%22%3A102%2C%22order%22%3A%22reverse_term%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.classification.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.classification.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.has_seal.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.has_seal.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.license.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.license.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.publisher.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.publisher.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.language.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.language.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%7D%7D&_=1513246254241"
```

In the above string I have to substitute an Integer in some place. For that I used %s.

```
s = S % 100
```

Then I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character 'B' (0x42) at index 51
```

**NOTE:** You can search (ctrl+f) for %s to see it in the  above string. I tried to highlight it. But it was not possible.

How can I substitute a value in the above string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: “substitute an Integer in some place”, substitute _where_?

Comment: Can you explain better?, show us the code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to avoid using `%s` for the substitution, and instead use `{}` with Python's `format()` function as follows:

```
text = "191042709832779540946_1513246254239&source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22match_all%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22from%22%3A{}%2C%22size%22%3A20000%2C%22facets%22%3A%7B%22_type%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22_type%22%2C%22size%22%3A102%2C%22order%22%3A%22reverse_term%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.classification.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.classification.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.has_seal.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.has_seal.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.license.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.license.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.publisher.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.publisher.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.language.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.language.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%7D%7D&_=1513246254241"
replace = 100

print text.format(replace)
```

This would give you:

```
191042709832779540946_1513246254239&source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22match_all%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22from%22%3A100%2C%22size%22%3A20000%2C%22facets%22%3A%7B%22_type%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22_type%22%2C%22size%22%3A102%2C%22order%22%3A%22reverse_term%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.classification.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.classification.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.has_seal.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.has_seal.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.license.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.license.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.publisher.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.publisher.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%2C%22index.language.exact%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22index.language.exact%22%2C%22size%22%3A110%2C%22order%22%3A%22count%22%7D%7D%7D%7D&_=1513246254241
```

This is necessary as your `text` already has other `%` characters and this will not be compatible with the `%s` substitution. By using this method, `replace` could also be a string if needed.

Comment: As a side note, `replace` can be anything, so the OP can use directly the number without having to convert it to string first (the example with `"XXX"` might be confusing in that respect).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use replace

```
newS = S.replace("%s", "100")
```

Here the usual syntax with `%` is difficult to apply because in your string there are a lot of '%x' that python do not take literally (it thinks they are placeholders for some other replacements, but in your caes there are just escaped HTML characters)